# findOneAndUpdate does not work after upgrading mongoose version from 3.8.22 to 4.3.2 on MongoDB Server 3.0.15

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I upgraded the mongoose version from 3.8.22 to 4.3.0 but `findOneAndUpdate` function doesn't work. It returns `null`.

```js
req.app.db.models.User.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, fieldsToSet, function(err, user) {
      console.log(err, user);
      if (err) {
        return workflow.emit('exception', err);
      }

      if (!user) {
        return workflow.emit('response');
      }
      workflow.emit('sendEmail', token, user);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including "mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);" in your program.

There are a few known compatability issues when migrating from mongoose 3.x to 4.x. You can find more information in the mongoose compatibility docs located here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/compatibility.html